# Simulate click event not working in Jest and Enzyme

Tags: node.js, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have below code for button and onClick event.

**Button Code**

```
let btn: ButtonInterface = {
    onClick: onBtnClick,
    text: "submit"
  };
```

**onClick Event Handler**

```
const onBtnClick = (event: Event) => {
  // logic
}
```

**Using below to call onClick**

```
wrapper = mount(<Main/> // Main component has button and its function
wrapper.find(".main_btn").simulate('click');
```

This does not seem to work. Even tried using `prop('onClick')()` but didn't work, as it gives below error

```
Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined' prop onClick
```

I also checked the props of the button and it contains the click event.

```
 props: {
          className: 'main_btn',
          responsive: true,
          label: 'submit',
          variant: 'primary',
          'min-width': '100px',
          disabled: false,
          onClick: [Function: onClick]
```

**Button usage**

Main component has a Page component which takes in this button

```
<Page PrimaryButton={btn} />
```

How should i trigger this click event ?

Using Node12, Enzyme7 and Jest24

Comment: `.main_btn` or `.main-button`?

Comment: just a typo. updated

Comment: How is button used? May you show that too?

Comment: updated in the question

Comment: How does `Page` render `btn`? I'd like to know how react is rendering the object as a button.

Comment: It basically passed all this information as props to Page component where it renders in with a custom Button component taking in all the details present in "btn".
I have checked on UI it works as expected but in test cases it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Kinda like this? `<Button {...props.PrimaryButton} />`

Comment: Yes sort of .In that Page component that custom Button component takes in click event as well.
`
onClick={event => {
                      props.PrimaryButton!.onClick(event);
                    }}`

Comment: I can't duplicate your issue. Please make sure you have a [mcve]? https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-austin-2xoyv